# Regular expression pattern for allowing null and empty

Tags: regex, xml, xsd, regular-language

Iam using below regular expression currently in XSD as below

```
<xs:pattern value="[A-Z]{3}"/>
```

This is working fine for alphabets.

But iam trying to allow null also to this , but could not

i tried putting

```
[null]|[A-Z]{3}
```

but this is also not accepting null.

I want null or empty to be accepted.

please help

Comment: I think that would be `([A-Z]{3}|)`. Notice the alteration which will allow blank or empty string.

Comment: Or `<xs:pattern value="([A-Z]{3})?"/>`. Note that a regex operates on text and cannot determine a `null` value, only an empty string.

Comment: What do you mean by "null"? are you talking about the character string ('n', 'u', 'l', 'l'), or about something else? There is no concept of "null" in any of the XML specifications, so it's not clear what you are talking about. In addition, there are several possible meanings of "empty".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A regex operates on text and cannot determine if  a string is `null`, it can only determine if a string is empty.

To make a match optional, you can enclose the whole pattern into a (non-)capturing group and add a `?` quantifier after it:

```
<xs:pattern value="([A-Z]{3})?"/>
```

Since the [pattern regex is anchored by default](http://www.regular-expressions.info/xml.html), this `([A-Z]{3})?` will match either an empty string or a string that only has 3 uppercase ASCII letters.